# separable BV space for PDE's, Whats stopping us?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the metric space BV(0,1) with the following metric
$$ d(u,v) = \|u-v\|_{L^1} + |TV(u)-TV(v)| $$. It is separable, compact, uniformly bounded and complete. So What is the really obvious thing that is stopping us from using this space for DE's and PDE problems!

[Reference](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1936-040-03/S0002-9947-1936-1501882-8/)

If any work is there, please reference it.

Comment: I quote my answer from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157703/energy-method-for-elliptic-pde/158657#158657): "in solving PDEs, one does not choose a function space first. Instead, one chooses a method and finds a function space in which the method can be applied. In fact, a large and necessary part of modern analysis of partial differential equations consists of clever choices of function spaces in order to implement certain solution schemes."

Comment: So the "obvious thing" would be that the solution schemes used by people studying DE and PDE require certain properties that is not satisfied by the space listed. That said, bounded variation function spaces (in general) are used to study 1+1 dimensional conservation laws. A large part of the theory of shocks that originated with Lax and Glimm is built upon BV spaces. So I don't really get your question.

Comment: @WillieWong : I am interested in works on using the exact metric space mentioned, and not just BV as a Banach space!

Comment: If you look at the reference I gave, there is a concept of vector metric space, where continuous linear functionals need not be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Willie : Also, could you please give a quick reference to the works on 1+1 conservation laws.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/Decay_of_Solutions_of_Systems_of_Nonline.html?id=Wrg9HMejTbsC  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160180408/abstract  for your last comment. To your original question: what makes you think that your metric space is good/not good for PDEs?

Comment: I don't exactly get your point either, @RajeshDachiraju. $BV$ is usually a proxy for the space $W^{1,1}$, so it's a space where energy functionals (like the TV-functional) are defined and minimised, rather than taken as an ambient space. But if this instances are ok for you, then there is a lot you can discover in the neighbourhood of the calculus of variations: e.g., P.L. Lions has worked on the mathematical theory of image processing in that space and Kawohl has proved a Cheeger inequality working on $BV$.

Comment: To be precise: 1) This distance comes from a Banach space norm.  2) It Is NOT compact as claimed, and not even locally compact (for TVS, LC=finite dimension. 3) It is a dual space, so that its closed unit ball is compact in the w* topology by Banach-Alaoglu, and it is also metrizable due to separability (the distance being strictly weaker than the one you wrote). 4) However on the whole space, the w* topology is not metrizable.

Comment: @PietroMajer : plz take a close look at second term on the right of equation. This is not coming from a norm.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju This metric actually seems weird to me: it is *not* equivalent to the usual metric $d(u,v)=TV(u-v)$ on BV spaces. To wit, let $u$ and $v$ be bounded by $\epsilon$ and have the same total variation, but $u$ oscillates wildly on $[0,1/3]$ and $v$ oscillates like crazy on $[2/3,1]$. Then $u$ and $v$ will be $2\epsilon$ close in your metric, but very far away in the standard BV metric.

Comment: @Fan : yes i know. Thats why i am nterested in it. I want to study this metric space. I know its not having anything to do with banach space.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju If that is your question, then I think you should read the first comment of Willie Wong, in particular this line: "in solving PDEs, one does not choose a function space first. Instead, one chooses a method and finds a function space in which the method can be applied." If your metric doesn't show up much in the literature, that is probably just a sign that it isn't a good one for expressing "closeness" in the BV sense.

Comment: Ok,  but i want to fibd a pde for which this space is suitable!

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju That's probably "putting the cart before the horse", again quoting Wille Wong, but good luck anyway!

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: right, I misread for $TV(u-v)$, sorry.  So in this convergence  $u_n$ converges to $u$ iff $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ and  $TV(u_n)$ converges to $TV(u)$. This convergence should be equivalent to w* convergence of $Du_n$ to $Du$ as measures on the compact set clos($\Omega$): no mass escapes to $\partial\Omega$. Have a look to Tigth Convergence of Measures.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Ambrosio's paper "Transport equation and Cauchy problem for BV vector fields", Invent. Math. 158 (2004), no. 2, 227–260 and at the references therein. The author is proving that bounded $BV$ vector fields with bounded divergence do have a flow, in an Eulerian sense, that is the IVP defined by the vector field has unique weak solutions (in $L^\infty$).